# How to write regular expression to find exact word at 10th position in Javascript adobe?

Tags: javascript, regex, adobe

I have been trying to write regular expression which find a specific word at specific position in javascript adobe classification rule builder

```
DI_NEO_OP_BRA_CRC_LRN_DIS_EP_NA_CON_UC_NA
```

I want to get result as CON from above line in adobe classification rule builder code which i have been using to get the desired output is

```
^(.+?)\_(.+?)\_(.+?)\_(.+?)\_(.+?)\_(.+?)\_(.+?)\_(.+?)\_(.+?)\_(.+?)\_(.+?)$
```

however this code only give output as any word which is at 10th position? I want to get output which matches CON and is at 10th position.

Comment: Do you mean like this? `^(?:[^_\n]*_){9}([^_\n]+)` https://regex101.com/r/FrFEqJ/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird Yes but in different way i want to mentioned CON in this regular expression too

Answer (score 1):

You can use a single capture group, and then match CON followed by either `_` or the end of the string:

```
^(?:[^_\n]*_){9}(CON)(?:_|$)
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:[^_\n]*_){9}` Repeat 9 times matching any character except `_` or a newline, and then match `_`
- `(CON)` Capture **group 1**, match CON
- `(?:_|$)` Match either `_` or assert the end of the string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FxfJ7l/1)

Comment: thanks for ur response but i only want to get CON as a result it is giving me answer but i only want it to return result as CON

Comment: @PriyaTiwari Are you using Javascript? How are you using the pattern?

Comment: I am using this in adobe classification rule builder and it is returning me 2 results 1 st is  DI_NEO_OP_BRA_CRC_LRN_DIS_EP_NA_CON_ and 2nd is CON but i only want 2nd result to make rule in adobe launch

Comment: @PriyaTiwari If you want a single match only you can try the pattern in the other answer but I am not sure if an infinite quantifier in a lookbehind assertion is supported in that environment. Is there no way that you can work with the second value (the capture group 1 value) in adobe classification rule builder?

Comment: unfortunately not, is there a way to get exact 2nd value ?

Comment: @PriyaTiwari Not really, if there are always 12 items, you can match CON and then assert 2 parts to the right till the end of the string `CON(?=(?:_[^\n_]+){2}$)` https://regex101.com/r/rPxvIy/1

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<=              # Match after
  ^               # the beginning of the line, then
  (?:[^_]+_)      #         1+ non-underscore chars followed by '_',
  {9}             # 9 times
)                 # 
CON               # literal 'CON',
(?=_|$)           # followed by '_' or end of line.
```

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/Js5nv5/4).